# Can I use a computed value in the parentheses of `require()` in JavaScript/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, require

I have a really simple app, that has a button.
When you press the button, the app plays a sound.
When I set the path of the file for the sound, I use `` require(`./assets/${array[0].bgm}.mp3`) ``.
However, I get an error.

How can I make it work?

[image: my app]

Here is an array, where I'm going to get the name `bgm` for the path:

array.js

```
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Ken",
    bgm: "bgm",
  },
];

export default array;
```

Here is app.js.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
import SoundPlayer from "./SoundPlayer";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SoundPlayer />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

Here is another file that contains `require()`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

import array from "./array";

export default function SoundPlayer() {
  const [sound, setSound] = React.useState();

  async function playSound() {
    console.log("Loading Sound");
    if (sound) {
      console.log("Unloading Sound");
      await sound.unloadAsync();
    }
    const { sound: newSound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      require(`./assets/${array[0].bgm}.mp3`) // This doesn't work.

      //require("./assets/bgm.mp3") //This just works.
     
    );
    setSound(newSound);

    console.log("Playing Sound");
    await newSound.playAsync();
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          console.log("Unloading Sound");
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  return <Button title="Play Sound" onPress={playSound} />;
}
```

However, this throws an error:

> error: SoundPlayer.js: SoundPlayer.js:Invalid call at line 17: require("./assets/" + _array.default[0].bgm + ".mp3")

I need some help.
How would you solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes maybe that'll work and you can try printing the whole thing ./assets/${test}.mp3, to get the desired output bcz as u said it was working when it's only string

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried it, but I got this error... : ```error: SoundPlayer.js: SoundPlayer.js:Invalid call at line 20: require("./assets/" + test + ".mp3")```

Comment: can you also try const tst = `./assets/${array[0]["bgm"]}.mp3`, and then require(tst)

Comment: Okay I'll do try!

Comment: I tried it, but I got almost the same error: SoundPlayer.js: SoundPlayer.js:Invalid call at line 21: require(tst)    Those things should make it work!! but didn't... I only see no error with ```require("./assets/bgm.mp3")``` but I need to make it dynamic, not a hardcord

Comment: Does this answer your question? [require() not working with variable - react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55852013/require-not-working-with-variable-react-native)

Comment: Wow yeah this works like a charm and soloved the all questions that I had! Thank you so much for the helps guys!